# How setup different secret and access key for celery in airflow.cfg file?

Tags: airflow, celery, airflow-celery

There is airflow with celery. `Airflow.cfg` looks like:

```
[celery]
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery
default_queue = myqueue
broker_url = sqs://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/111111111111
```

So for `SQS` celery uses `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` system variables. But these variables are used by airflow too.
Is there a way to setup different credentials? For example set `CELERY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `CELERY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` for celery
only and do not share `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` with other services? Any example with config are welcome.

Note: using `predefined_queues` is not en optiona because there are multiple different queues